# How to "fix [line:(no source Location)]" when I transfer my code from eclipse to dr.java?

Tags: java, eclipse, drjava

When I try to transfer my eclipse source code to dr.java, the first line "package TrigonometricCalculators;" doesn't work.

The compiler gives me

> "File: C:\Users\TwlEm\Desktop\TrigCalculators.java  [line: (no source location)]
>   Error: File is in the wrong directory or is declared part of the wrong package.  Directory name 'Desktop' does not match package name 'TrigonometricCalculators'."

On my own PC, I delete this error line and it works but when I do so on a school computer, my whole program crashes. How to solve this problem?

```
package TrigonometricCalculators;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class TrigCalculators {
 private JFrame frame;
 private StringBuilder sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 double firstnum;
 double secondnum;
 String operations;
 double result;
 String answer;
 double product=1;
 static boolean equalsAlreadyPressed = false;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    try {
     TrigCalculators window = new TrigCalculators();
     window.frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  });
 }
 public TrigCalculators() {
  initialize();
 }
 private void initialize() {
   frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 473, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JButton btn0 = new JButton("0");
    btn0.setBounds(35, 438, 55, 55);
    btn0.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btn0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      sBuilder.append("0");
      lblNewLabel.setText(sBuilder.toString());
     }
    });
    btn0.setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btn0);

    JButton btn1 = new JButton("1");
    btn1.setBounds(35, 372, 55, 55);
    btn1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btn1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      sBuilder.append("1");
      lblNewLabel.setText(sBuilder.toString());  
      }
    });
    btn1.setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btn1);

    JButton btn2 = new JButton("2");
    btn2.setBounds(100, 372, 55, 55);
    btn2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btn2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      sBuilder.append("2");
      lblNewLabel.setText(sBuilder.toString());
     }
    });
    btn2.setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btn2);

    JButton btn3 = new JButton("3");
    btn3.setBounds(165, 372, 55, 55);
    btn3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btn3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      sBuilder.append("3");
      lblNewLabel.setText(sBuilder.toString());
     }
    });
    btn3.setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btn3);

    JButton btn4 = new JButton("4");
    btn4.setBounds(35, 306, 55, 55);
    btn4.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btn4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      sBuilder.append("4");
      lblNewLabel.setText(sBuilder.toString());
     }
    });
    btn4.setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btn4);

    JButton btn5 = new JButton("5");
    btn5.setBounds(100, 306, 55, 55);
    btn5.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btn5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      sBuilder.append("5");
      lblNewLabel.setText(sBuilder.toString());
     }
    });
    btn5.setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btn5);

    JButton btn6 = new JButton("6");
    btn6.setBounds(165, 306, 55, 55);
    btn6.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btn6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      sBuilder.append("6");
      lblNewLabel.setText(sBuilder.toString());
     }
    });
    btn6.setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btn6);

    JButton btn7 = new JButton("7");
    btn7.setBounds(35, 240, 55, 55);
    btn7.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btn7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      sBuilder.append("7");
      lblNewLabel.setText(sBuilder.toString());
     }
    });
    btn7.setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btn7);

    JButton btn8 = new JButton("8");
    btn8.setBounds(100, 240, 55, 55);
    btn8.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btn8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      sBuilder.append("8");
      lblNewLabel.setText(sBuilder.toString());
     }
    });
    btn8.setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btn8);

    JButton btn9 = new JButton("9");
    btn9.setBounds(165, 240, 55, 55);
    btn9.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btn9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      sBuilder.append("9");
      lblNewLabel.setText(sBuilder.toString());
     }
    });
    btn9.setBackground(SystemColor.controlHighlight);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btn9);

    JButton button = new JButton("");
    button.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
    button.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    button.setBounds(360, 110, 55, 43);
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);

    JButton btnsin = new JButton("sin");
    btnsin.setBounds(35, 169, 55, 55);
    btnsin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      firstnum = Double.parseDouble(sBuilder.toString());
      sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      lblNewLabel.setText("sin");
      operations ="sin" ;
      equalsAlreadyPressed = false;
     }
    });
    btnsin.setFont(new Font("STXinwei", Font.BOLD, 13));
    btnsin.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnsin);

    JButton btncos = new JButton("cos");
    btncos.setBounds(100, 169, 55, 55);
    btncos.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      firstnum = Double.parseDouble(sBuilder.toString());
      sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      lblNewLabel.setText("cos");
      operations ="cos" ;
      equalsAlreadyPressed = false;
     }
    });
    btncos.setFont(new Font("STXinwei", Font.BOLD, 13));
    btncos.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btncos);

    JButton btnTan = new JButton("tan");
    btnTan.setBounds(165, 169, 55, 55);
    btnTan.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      firstnum = Double.parseDouble(sBuilder.toString());
      sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      lblNewLabel.setText("tan");
      operations ="tan" ;
      equalsAlreadyPressed = false;
     }
    });
    btnTan.setFont(new Font("STXinwei", Font.BOLD, 13));
    btnTan.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnTan);

    JButton btncsc = new JButton("csc");
    btncsc.setBounds(230, 169, 55, 55);
    btncsc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      firstnum = Double.parseDouble(sBuilder.toString());
      sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      lblNewLabel.setText("csc");
      operations ="csc" ;
      equalsAlreadyPressed = false;
     }
    });
    btncsc.setFont(new Font("STXinwei", Font.BOLD, 13));
    btncsc.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btncsc);

    JButton btnsec = new JButton("sec");
    btnsec.setBounds(295, 169, 55, 55);
    btnsec.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      firstnum = Double.parseDouble(sBuilder.toString());
      sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      lblNewLabel.setText("sec");
      operations ="sec" ;
      equalsAlreadyPressed = false;
     }
    });
    btnsec.setFont(new Font("STXinwei", Font.BOLD, 13));
    btnsec.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnsec);

    JButton btnCot = new JButton("cot");
    btnCot.setBounds(360, 169, 55, 55);
    btnCot.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      firstnum = Double.parseDouble(sBuilder.toString());
      sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      lblNewLabel.setText("cot");
      operations ="cot" ;
      equalsAlreadyPressed = false;
     }
    });
    btnCot.setFont(new Font("STXinwei", Font.BOLD, 13));
    btnCot.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnCot);

    JButton btnArcsin = new JButton("asin");
    btnArcsin.setBounds(35, 110, 75, 43);
    btnArcsin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      firstnum = Double.parseDouble(sBuilder.toString());
      sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      lblNewLabel.setText("arcsin");
      operations ="arcsin" ;
      equalsAlreadyPressed = false;
     }
    });
    btnArcsin.setFont(new Font("STXinwei", Font.BOLD, 12));
    btnArcsin.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnArcsin);

    JButton btnArccos = new JButton("acos");
    btnArccos.setBounds(122, 110, 75, 43);
    btnArccos.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      firstnum = Double.parseDouble(sBuilder.toString());
      sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      lblNewLabel.setText("arccos");
      operations ="arccos" ;
      equalsAlreadyPressed = false;
     }
    });
    btnArccos.setFont(new Font("STXinwei", Font.BOLD, 12));
    btnArccos.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnArccos);

    JButton btnArctan = new JButton("atan");
    btnArctan.setBounds(210, 110, 75, 43);
    btnArctan.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      firstnum = Double.parseDouble(sBuilder.toString());
      sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      lblNewLabel.setText("arctan");
      operations ="arctan" ;
      equalsAlreadyPressed = false;
     }
    });
    btnArctan.setFont(new Font("STXinwei", Font.BOLD, 12));
    btnArctan.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnArctan);

    JButton btnpower = new JButton("a^b");
    btnpower.setBounds(230, 242, 55, 55);
    btnpower.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      firstnum = Double.parseDouble(sBuilder.toString());
      sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      lblNewLabel.setText("^");
      operations ="^" ;
      equalsAlreadyPressed = false;
     }
    });
    btnpower.setFont(new Font("Sylfaen", Font.BOLD, 10));
    btnpower.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnpower);

    JButton btnAbs = new JButton("abs");
    btnAbs.setBounds(295, 110, 55, 43);
    btnAbs.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      firstnum = Double.parseDouble(sBuilder.toString());
      sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      lblNewLabel.setText("abs");
      operations ="abs" ;
      equalsAlreadyPressed = false;
     }
    });
    btnAbs.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 11));
    btnAbs.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnAbs);

    JButton btnaddition = new JButton("+");
    btnaddition.setBounds(230, 372, 55, 55);
    btnaddition.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btnaddition.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      firstnum = Double.parseDouble(sBuilder.toString());
      sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      lblNewLabel.setText("+");
      operations ="+" ;
      equalsAlreadyPressed = false;
     }
    });
    btnaddition.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnaddition);

    JButton btnmultiplication = new JButton("\u00D7");
    btnmultiplication.setBounds(230, 306, 55, 55);
    btnmultiplication.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btnmultiplication.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      firstnum = Double.parseDouble(sBuilder.toString());
      sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      lblNewLabel.setText("×");
      operations ="×" ;
      equalsAlreadyPressed = false;
     }
    });
    btnmultiplication.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnmultiplication);

    JButton btndelete = new JButton("DEL");
    btndelete.setBounds(295, 438, 55, 55);
    btndelete.setForeground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    btndelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      if (!"".equals(sBuilder.toString())) {
       sBuilder.deleteCharAt(sBuilder.length() - 1);
       lblNewLabel.setText(sBuilder.toString());
      }
     }
    });
    btndelete.setFont(new Font("STXinwei", Font.BOLD, 10));
    btndelete.setBackground(SystemColor.textInactiveText);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btndelete);

    JButton btnDot = new JButton(".");
    btnDot.setBounds(360, 372, 55, 55);
    btnDot.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btnDot.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      sBuilder.append(".");
      lblNewLabel.setText(sBuilder.toString());
     }
    });
    btnDot.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnDot);

    JButton btnlog = new JButton("log");
    btnlog.setBounds(295, 242, 55, 55);
    btnlog.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      firstnum = Double.parseDouble(sBuilder.toString());
      sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      lblNewLabel.setText("log");
      operations ="log" ;
      equalsAlreadyPressed = false;
     }
    });
    btnlog.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 10));
    btnlog.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnlog);

    JButton btnsubstraction = new JButton("-");
    btnsubstraction.setBounds(295, 372, 55, 55);
    btnsubstraction.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btnsubstraction.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      firstnum = Double.parseDouble(sBuilder.toString());
      sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      lblNewLabel.setText("-");
      operations ="-" ;
      equalsAlreadyPressed = false;
     }
    });
    btnsubstraction.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnsubstraction);

    JButton btndivision = new JButton("\u00F7");
    btndivision.setBounds(295, 306, 55, 55);
    btndivision.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btndivision.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      firstnum = Double.parseDouble(sBuilder.toString());
      sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      lblNewLabel.setText("÷");
      operations = "÷";
      equalsAlreadyPressed = false;
     }
    });
    btndivision.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btndivision);

    JButton btnfactorial = new JButton("!");
    btnfactorial.setBounds(360, 240, 55, 55);
    btnfactorial.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btnfactorial.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      firstnum = Double.parseDouble(sBuilder.toString());
      sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      lblNewLabel.setText("!");
      operations ="!" ;
      equalsAlreadyPressed = false;
     }
    });
    btnfactorial.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnfactorial);

    JButton btnAc = new JButton("AC");
    btnAc.setBounds(360, 439, 55, 55);
    btnAc.setForeground(SystemColor.text);
    btnAc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      lblNewLabel.setText(null);
      equalsAlreadyPressed = false;
     }

    });
    btnAc.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 12));
    btnAc.setBackground(SystemColor.textInactiveText);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnAc);

    JButton btnmode = new JButton("%");
    btnmode.setBounds(360, 306, 55, 55);
    btnmode.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 15));
    btnmode.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      firstnum = Double.parseDouble(sBuilder.toString());
      sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
      lblNewLabel.setText("%");
      operations ="%" ;
      equalsAlreadyPressed = false;
     }
    });
    btnmode.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnmode);

    JButton btnequal = new JButton("=");
    btnequal.setBounds(230, 438, 55, 55);
    btnequal.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 16));
    btnequal.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

      if((operations=="+")||(operations=="-")||(operations=="×")||(operations=="÷")||(operations=="log")||(operations=="^")||(operations=="%")) {
      secondnum = Double.parseDouble(sBuilder.toString());
            if(!equalsAlreadyPressed) {
         if (operations=="+"&&!equalsAlreadyPressed) {
          result = firstnum + secondnum;
          answer= String.valueOf(result);  
          lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
          sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
          sBuilder.append(answer);
          equalsAlreadyPressed = true;
         } else if (operations=="-" && !equalsAlreadyPressed) {
          result = firstnum -secondnum;
          answer= String.valueOf(result);
          lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
          sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
          sBuilder.append(answer);
          equalsAlreadyPressed = true;
         } else if (operations=="×" && !equalsAlreadyPressed) {
          result = firstnum * secondnum;
          answer= String.valueOf(result);
         lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
         sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
         sBuilder.append(answer);
         equalsAlreadyPressed = true;
         } else if (operations=="÷" && !equalsAlreadyPressed) {
          equalsAlreadyPressed = true;
          if(!(secondnum==0) ) {    //if the second number is not 0 
           result= firstnum/ secondnum;
           answer= String.valueOf(result);
           lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
           sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
           sBuilder.append(result);
          }
          else {
           lblNewLabel.setText("Math Error");
          }
         }else if(operations=="^" && !equalsAlreadyPressed){
          result = Math.pow(firstnum, secondnum) ;
          answer= String.valueOf(result);
            lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
            sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            sBuilder.append(answer);
            equalsAlreadyPressed = true;
         }else if (operations=="%" && !equalsAlreadyPressed) {
          result = firstnum % secondnum;
          answer= String.valueOf(result);
          lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
          sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
          sBuilder.append(answer);
          equalsAlreadyPressed = true;
         } else if (operations=="log" && !equalsAlreadyPressed) {
          if((firstnum>0)&&(firstnum!=1)&&(secondnum>0)) {
          result= Math.log(secondnum)/(Math.log(firstnum));
          answer= String.valueOf(result);
            lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
            sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            sBuilder.append(result);
            equalsAlreadyPressed = true;
          }else{
           lblNewLabel.setText("Math Error");
          }

         }else {
            lblNewLabel.setText(sBuilder.toString());
           }
      }else {
       lblNewLabel.setText("Syntax Error");
      }
     }else if (operations=="!") {
        if(!equalsAlreadyPressed) {
       if (firstnum<0) {
        lblNewLabel.setText("Math Error");
       }
       else if(firstnum==0) {
        result = 1;
        answer= String.valueOf(result);
            lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
            sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            sBuilder.append(answer);
       }
       else if (firstnum>0) {
        int testfactorial = (int)firstnum;
        if((testfactorial/firstnum)==1) {
         for(int i =1;i<=firstnum;i++) {
          product=product*i;
         }
         result = product;
               answer= String.format("%.0f", result);
               lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
               sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
               sBuilder.append(answer);
               equalsAlreadyPressed = true;
        }
        else {
         lblNewLabel.setText("Math Error");
        }
       }
     }else {
     lblNewLabel.setText("Syntax Error");
        }
     }else if ((operations=="sin")||(operations=="cos")||(operations=="tan")||(operations=="csc")||(operations=="sec")||(operations=="cot")||(operations=="abs")||(operations=="arcsin")||(operations=="arccos")||(operations=="arctan")) {
        if (operations=="sin"&&!equalsAlreadyPressed) {
        result = Math.sin(firstnum) ;
        answer= String.valueOf(result);
          lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
          sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
          sBuilder.append(answer);
          equalsAlreadyPressed = true;
       }else if(operations=="cos"&&!equalsAlreadyPressed) {
        result = Math.cos(firstnum) ;
        answer= String.valueOf(result);
          lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
          sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
          sBuilder.append(answer);
          equalsAlreadyPressed = true;
       }else if(operations=="tan"&&!equalsAlreadyPressed) {
        double testtan= (firstnum-((Math.PI)/2))/(Math.PI);
        int testtanint= (int)testtan;
         if(testtanint/testtan==1) {
          lblNewLabel.setText("Math Error");

         }else {
          result = Math.tan(firstnum) ;
          answer= String.valueOf(result);
            lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
            sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            sBuilder.append(answer);
            equalsAlreadyPressed = true;
         }
       }else if(operations=="csc"&&!equalsAlreadyPressed) {
        double testcsc=(firstnum/(Math.PI));
        int testcscint=(int)testcsc;
         if(testcscint/testcsc==1) {
          lblNewLabel.setText("Math Error");

         }else {

          result = 1/(Math.sin(firstnum));
          answer= String.valueOf(result);
            lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
            sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            sBuilder.append(answer);
            equalsAlreadyPressed = true;
         }
       }else if(operations=="sec"&&!equalsAlreadyPressed) {
        double testsec= (firstnum-((Math.PI)/2))/(Math.PI);
        int testsecint= (int)testsec;
        if(testsecint/testsec==1) {
         lblNewLabel.setText("Math Error");
        }else {
         result = 1/(Math.cos(firstnum)) ;
         answer= String.valueOf(result);
           lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
           sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
           sBuilder.append(answer);
           equalsAlreadyPressed = true;
        }
       }else if(operations=="cot"&&!equalsAlreadyPressed) {
        double testcot= (firstnum)/(Math.PI);
        int testcotint= (int)testcot;
        if(testcotint/testcot==1) {
         lblNewLabel.setText("Math Error");
        }else {
         result = 1/(Math.tan(firstnum)) ;
         answer= String.valueOf(result);
           lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
           sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
           sBuilder.append(answer);
           equalsAlreadyPressed = true;
        }
       }else if(operations=="arcsin"&&!equalsAlreadyPressed) {
        if(firstnum>=(-1)&&firstnum<=(1)) {
        result =Math.asin(firstnum) ;
        answer= String.valueOf(result);
          lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
          sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
          sBuilder.append(answer);
          equalsAlreadyPressed = true;
        }else {
         lblNewLabel.setText("Math Error");
        }
       }else if(operations=="arccos"&&!equalsAlreadyPressed) {
        if(firstnum>=(-1)&&firstnum<=(1)) {
        result = Math.acos(firstnum) ;
        answer= String.valueOf(result);
          lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
          sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
          sBuilder.append(answer);
          equalsAlreadyPressed = true;
        }else {
         lblNewLabel.setText("Math Error");
        }
       }else if(operations=="arctan"&&!equalsAlreadyPressed) {
        result = Math.atan(firstnum) ;
        answer= String.valueOf(result);
          lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
          sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
          sBuilder.append(answer);
          equalsAlreadyPressed = true;
       }else if(operations=="abs"&&!equalsAlreadyPressed) {
        if(firstnum>=0) {
        result = firstnum;
        answer= String.valueOf(result);
          lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
          sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
          sBuilder.append(answer);
          equalsAlreadyPressed = true;
        }else {
         result = firstnum*(-1);
         answer= String.valueOf(result);
           lblNewLabel.setText(answer.toString());
           sBuilder = new StringBuilder();
           sBuilder.append(answer);
           equalsAlreadyPressed = true;
        }
         }
     }
     } 
    });
    btnequal.setBackground(SystemColor.inactiveCaption);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnequal);
 }
}
```

Comment: *"my whole program crashes"* With what error?

Comment: I use the JButton and on the JButton line "lblNewLabel.setText(sBuilder.toString());"
, it says, "local variable is accessed from within inner class needs to be declared final java"

Comment: I have tried to avoid copying and pasting and I use the export key to retransfer my code but it seems does not work.

Comment: That's a compilation error, not a runtime error causing "crash". Fix the code to be valid, and compiles without errors, before you try running it. --- That's way too much code for us to look at. The compilation error message will tell you the line number where the bad code was detected. Look there.

Comment: How to "fix the code to be valid"?

Comment: I don't understand why the code is valid on one computer but invalid on another. As well, it works well on eclipse ide

Comment: No idea, because you still haven't told us which of the ***704!!!*** lines is causing the error. You might want to read [How to create a **Minimal**, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You question talks about an error to do with `package`. Your comment is about an error to do with local variable not being final. Which error are you asking about now?

Comment: oh. the problem is : when i open these codes in dr.java ide, the compiler shows me "Error: File is in the wrong directory or is declared part of the wrong package. Directory name 'Desktop' does not match package name 'TrigonometricCalculators'." other lines are good. So i deleted the package line in order to fix the error. However, after I deleted the package line, I cause other errors on line 44 and 56, which says variable not being final.

Comment: Sounds like it is using an older version of Java than you are. In Java 8 (and later), local variables don't have to be declared `final`, since the compiler can infer *effectively-final*. In Java 7 (and earlier), a variable declared outside an anonymous class, but used inside, must be declared `final`.

Comment: Okay. That must be the problem. I was using Java 7. Thank you so so much!